# Java 8 group parent child objects

Tags: java, spring

I have a list of java POJO that's coming from a third party mysql stored procedure that includes location information mainly region,city,building and floor and the incident count for each location grouped by floors. I need to aggregate the incident count for each region,city and building as well. I also need to collect the children under each parent in a POJO as a location tree:
how can I do this with java stream api ? Thanks in advance!

input data :

[image]

output json :

```
[{
    label : "EMEA",
    type : "REGION",
    incidentCount : 78,
    children : [
        {
                label : "PAIS",
                type : "CITY",
                incidentCount : 37,
                children : [
                    {
                        label: "F1",
                        TYPE : "FLOOR",
                        incidentCount: 18
                    },
                    {
                        label: "F2",
                        TYPE : "FLOOR",
                        incidentCount: 19
                    },
                    ...
                ]
        },
        ...
    ]
},
...
]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. --- Why the limitation on using the stream API?

Comment: please provide the input data coded in java, and your attempt.